# Can't ping from my office to my home PC

Tags: windows-7, networking, ip, ping, remote-access

Usually, I used TeamViewer to control my home PC and my office iMac both ways.

But `TeamViewer` doesn't work sometimes. In this case, from my home PC to my office iMac, I used `UltraVnc` (on home PC) to control office iMac.

But if I am in my office, want to connect to home PC but when `TeamViewer` doesn't work, I have no way to control the home PC.

The problem is that, even I use `Terminal` (on iMac) to `ping` my home PC, there is no result.

I have followed [Tutorial](http://www.sysprobs.com/enable-ping-reply-windows-7) to enable my home PC to be pinged.
It doens't work. Even if I turn off Windows 7 Firewall to test, I still can't ping home PC from my office.

I really wish to be able to control my home PC from my office.
My ip is something like `89.97.123.123` (This is not my ip anyway...), and it is provided by a French company `Bouygue Telecom`.

Please help me to the setting on Windows 7 to be controled outside my home. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, it's normal you can't ping your PC from the outside : your bbox is in between, but according to https://lafibre.info/bbox-adsl/bbox-sensation-bloque-les-pings-entrants/24/ can't respond to the ping requests...

In case you'd like to use ultra vnc you will need to do some natting. In the NAT rules of your box, add a line where you redirect the incoming connections on port `5900` to your PC running a vnc server port `5900`.

Ref : http://www.smartlab.at/mobilevnc/vnc-behind-a-firewall-or-a-nat-router/

**Edit :** I was maybe a bit violent in my answer, sorry for that ;-)

A NAT is a set of rules based on ip and port defined in a router to perform routing of traffic. In your case, you'd like your box to route the incoming VNC traffic to your PC.

To do such a thing, all you have to do is to connect on your bbox web and interface and use the dedicated NAT menu (check this page http://www.01net.com/editorial/552354/configurez-correctement-votre-bbox/ for more detailed help, I don't have such a box at home).

Then, you can use this rule :

```
"Name of the rule"  TCP  Port  5900  [ip_local_pc]  5900
```

Hope it helped

Comment: Thank you, Toine42. But let me ask a (stupid?) question, where I can modify "NAT rules of my box too add a line"? I am just a normal user (not `superuser` ) and I don't understand the terms like `NAT` or `routers`, but I know I have a box (which is called bbox)

Comment: I've edited my answer, to be a little clearer. Note that you need on your local PC a VNC server running such as `real vnc`

Comment: Thank you again (Merci!). Now when TeamViewer doesn't work, I can use VNC to control my home PC.